# Add 802.1x network in Android 10+

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0

I am trying to add a 802.1x network programmatically in my Android app.
On an Android 8 device using addNetwork I see that the network is added with credentials but on Android 10 and above, when using addNetworkSuggestions, the credentials are not added.
I am new in this field so it is possible I am missing something vital.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
wifiConf.allowedProtocols.clear();
wifiConf.SSID = TextUtil.convertToQuotedString(apSsid.toString());

wifiConf.enterpriseConfig = eapConfig.asWifiEnterpriseConfig();
wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(......);
wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(......);
wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.NONE);

wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

wifiConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

if (apPass.length() == 64 && WeFiUtilExt.isHex(apPass)) {
   // Goes unquoted as hex
   wifiConf.preSharedKey = apPass;
} 
else {
   // Goes quoted as ASCII
   wifiConf.preSharedKey = TextUtil.convertToQuotedString(apPass);
}


WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();
wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.setSsid(ssid).setIsAppInteractionRequired(true);
wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.setWpa2EnterpriseConfig(wifiEnterpriseConfig);
WifiNetworkSuggestion wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestion = wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.build();
    

WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();
wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.setSsid(ssid).setIsAppInteractionRequired(false);
wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.setWpa3EnterpriseConfig(wifiEnterpriseConfig);
WifiNetworkSuggestion wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestion = wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.build();

List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> wifiNetworkSuggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
wifiNetworkSuggestionList.add(wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestion);
wifiNetworkSuggestionList.add(wpa3WifiNetworkSuggestion);

int addStatus = m_wifiMngr.addNetworkSuggestions(wifiNetworkSuggestionList);
```

The return code is 0 implying that the add worked.
Will this not work in Android 10+?

Comment: You are creating instances of a singleton. That´s probably messing with your code. Replace "WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();" with "WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder wpa2WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();" or better yet, use the singleton directly.

Comment: @FcoP. Not sure what you mean. WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder is a class that needs to be instantiated.